# Send Email to multiple users from a multiple selection List column using a work flow in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, email, user

How do you Send an Email to multiple users from a multiple selection List column using a workflow in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Which type of column do you have whether is it People or Group type or choice field?

Comment: People and Group

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple take "Email" activity in SharePoint 2010 Workflow.

Click on book as shown below and then click on **"Workflow lookup for user"**

[image]

Select column as shown below.

[image]

Please publish workflow and check whether it will work or not. In my environment it is working.

Comment: This workflow is not working in my environment. this is exactly what i wanted to to but it's not working...   Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: Have you use SharePoint group in people picker column value? Have you set up outgoing mail configuration?